# batch file to makecab file with password and extract it using password

Tags: batch-file, makefile, cab, makecab

i want batch file to make cab file using `makecab` with password and extract it using the same password (i want the two codes alone)

first code:

```
makecab /add %USERPROFILE%\DESKTOP\M.TXT M.zip /P:12345
```

second code:

```
makecab /extract %USERPROFILE%\DESKTOP\M.zip /P:12345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAKECAB does not support password protection and despite one of it's compression algorithms is `MSZIP` [it is not exactly a zip file](http://hackipedia.org/File%20formats/Containers/CAB,%20Microsoft%20CABinet%20compressed%20archive%20(archive)/Microsoft%20MSZIP%20Data%20Compression%20Format.rtf.pdf)

[Makecab user guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx)

My suggestion is to use `7za` (check comments for more info).

```
7za a  -p12345 m.zip m.txt
```

extract

```
7za a  -p12345 m.zip m.txt
```

`7za` can be downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/?source=typ_redirect)

Comment: this program include in windows ?? if not i want program include in windows

Comment: @user3752270 `MAKECAB` is included in every windows distribution out there.If using a third party tool is not a problem for you  - the most common choice is `7za` part of `7zip`  -> http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Comment: not problem if it not cab the important thing is when i compress it will include password (not problem if there is codes on vbs)

Comment: @user3752270 - vbscript/jscript/wsh support zipping and unzipping through `"Shell.Application"` (http://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili) (which is a scriptable part of windows explorer) but still it does not support password sets.It's possible to do this through `.net` which will require powershell or selfcompiled jscript program , but it will take me time.Still I think `7za` is the easiest way - check the reference - http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

Comment: @user3752270 - I'e updated my answer with `7za` examples.If you wish an powershell/.net solution you'll have to wait (still not sure if I'll have the time..)